# Issue in QT 5.2.1 app in linking libquazip.so library during making .deb package for ubuntu 14.04

Tags: deb, ubuntu-14.04, qt5.2, quazip

I am making .deb package for the QT 5 .2.1 desktop app for ubuntu 14.04 64 bit. I have installed QT 5.2.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 and made a demo app for the testing purpose in which I have used quazip library. During making the .deb package of the app I am getting the below issue.

**dpkg-shlibdeps: error: couldn’t find library libquazip.so.1 needed by debian/demoapp/usr/bin/DemoApp1 (ELF format: ‘elf64-x86-64’; RPATH: ‘’)
dpkg-shlibdeps: warning: package could avoid a useless dependency if debian/demoapp/usr/bin/DemoApp1 was not linked against libz.so.1 (it uses none of the library’s symbols)**
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: cannot continue due to the error above
Note: libraries are not searched in other binary packages that do not have any shlibs or symbols file.
To help dpkg-shlibdeps find private libraries, you might need to use -l.
dh_shlibdeps: dpkg-shlibdeps -Tdebian/demoapp.substvars debian/demoapp/usr/bin/DemoApp1 returned exit code 2
make: *** [binary-predeb-IMPL/demoapp] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules binary gave error exit status 2
debuild: fatal error at line 1364:
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc failed

**When I copy the libquazip.so.1 at the path /usr/lib in my machine then I got the below issue .**

**dpkg-shlibdeps: error: no dependency information found for /usr/lib/libquazip.so.1 (used by debian/demoapp/usr/bin/DemoApp1)**
dh_shlibdeps: dpkg-shlibdeps -Tdebian/demoapp.substvars debian/demoapp/usr/bin/DemoApp1 returned exit code 2
make: *** [binary-predeb-IMPL/demoapp] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules binary gave error exit status 2
debuild: fatal error at line 1364:
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc failed

**My cmakelist.txt file as per below.**

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.9)

project(DemoApp1)

set (CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH} “;/opt/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/gcc_64/lib/cmake;”)

find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)

include_directories(/home/manojpatidar/Manoj/Work/QT_WORK/Linux_Package/demoapp-1.0/lib/quazip-0.5.1/quazip)

link_directories(/home/manojpatidar/Manoj/Work/QT_WORK/Linux_Package/demoapp-1.0/lib/quazip-0.5.1)

add_executable(DemoApp1 main.cpp mainwindow.cpp moc_mainwindow.cpp mainwindow.ui)

target_link_libraries(DemoApp1 quazip z)

install(TARGETS DemoApp1 RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)

qt5_use_modules(DemoApp1 Widgets)

**My Debian control file is as per below .**

Source: demoapp

Section: games

Priority: extra

Maintainer: Manoj Patidar

Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 8.0.0), cmake, qtbase5-dev, cdbs

Standards-Version: 3.9.4

Package: demoapp

Architecture: any

Depends: ${shlibs:Depends}, ${misc:Depends}

Description: Description

Description will come here

I think I need to add some dependencies for quazip at the line “Depends: ${shlibs:Depends}, ${misc:Depends}” . Is there anything I have missed ? . Please have look into the issue and let me know where I did wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Can anyone please let me know how can I add quazip build dependency in debian control file at the line **Build-Depends:** and **Depends:** like **quazip-0.5.1 (>=0.5.1)** ? I am using quazip-0.5.1. I think I have missed to add this in control file.

Comment: You need to add libwhatever-dev to the Build-Depends

Comment: @LtWorf, thanks for your comment. Btw, Now I am using default "unzip" program of Ubuntu to extracting zip files.